# js style properties returns blank

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I am trying to receive the original CSS width value of an object using JavaScript. However, if I use:

```
var originalWidth = document.getElementById(<idOfObject>).style.width;
```

It always returns blank. I've also noticed that any property I access using this syntax will return blank. I know for sure that the given element exists, since

```
alert(document.getElementById(<idOfObject>));
```

does shows me the right object.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably try to get the value which was set in stylesheet, not directly like this:

```
document.getElementById(<idOfObject>).style.width = '100px';
```

If you want to get the width of the element you can use innerWidth property:

```
var width = document.getElementById(<idOfObject>).offsetWidth;
```

Comment: innerWidth or offsetWidth? Besides I'll add that you can access inline style properties, like here: <div style="width: 100px;">...</div>

Comment: I just figured it out myself, you were right! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: None of them, the correct is clientWidth; offsetWidth returns the width plus border width. innerWidth may return nothing if the property width is set by external css or even style setction

Answer (score 12):

None of the previous answers were right.

The property you are looking for is **clientWidth**, but not in "style"

```
document.getElementById('idOfObject').clientWidth;
```

That will work both on "width" set with external css, style seccion or even inline style="width:80px"

General note: don't use `<div width="500">` as it has no effect

The mentioned `offsetWidth` is the second best choice, but it does not return the exact width set in css, but that width plus border width

Other options like `innerWidth` that works with window object didn't work for me on divs.

This bizarre issue of realizing `style.width` not working properly, wasted 2 hours of my precious time :-), hope this answer shorts that time for anyone else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div  style="width:10%" id="mydiv" >
```

OR

```
<div  style="width:10px" id="mydiv" >

var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
 var curr_width = mydiv.style.width;
alert(curr_width);
```

This works for me

Answer (score 1):

I tried it and I can get the value

http://jsfiddle.net/xyd95/

Well, unless the `width` has no unit

http://jsfiddle.net/xyd95/1/

Comment: the difference was that I'd set the value in an external stylesheet. As bjornd said, the object.style.width can only show the inline DOM property of the object.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work

```
function getWidth()
{

x = document.getElementById(<idOfObject>)
return x.offsetWidth;
}
```